# awk print sum of group of lines

Tags: awk

I have a file with a column named (effect) which has rows separated by blank lines,

```
(effect)
    1
    1
    1
    
    (effect)
    1
    1
    1
    1
    
    
    (effect)
    1
    1
```

I know how to print the sum of column like

```
awk  '{sum+=$1;} END{print sum;}' file.txt
```

Using awk how can I print the sum of each (effect) in for loop? such that I have three lines or multiple lines in other cases like below

```
sum=3
 sum=4
 sum=2
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw).

Comment: Why do you want it in a `for loop`? Do you want a for loop inside the awk script or in the shell script that's calling the awk script?

Comment: I want for loop in awk or shell. because in my actual code i want to perform some other actions with the sum.

Comment: @Aprilian8 that still wouldn't require a for loop and, in fact, a for loop might be an anti-pattern depending on what it is you're really trying to do. If you post a question with an example of what 1 or more of those "other actions" is we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is an *(effect)* part, and print the sum when encountering either the (effect) part or when in the END block.

```
awk '
$1 == "(effect)" { if(seen) print "sum="sum; seen = 1; sum = 0 }
/[0-9]/ { sum += $1 }
END { if (seen) print "sum="sum }
' file
```

Output

```
sum=3
sum=4
sum=2
```

Comment: could you please explain the use of seen?

Comment: @Aprilian8 I use seen here to prevent writing just `sum=` without a value directly after the first time encountering "(effect)" and in the END block to only print `sum=` with a value (default 0) if there actually was a line with "(effect)"

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)?\\(effect\\)[^(]*' '
RT{
  gsub(/\(effect\)\n|\n+[[:space:]]*$/,"",RT)
  num=split(RT,arr,ORS)
  print "sum="num
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using GNU `awk`. In `awk` program set `RS` as `(^|\n)?\\(effect\\)[^(]*` regex for whole Input_file. In main program checking condition if `RT` is NOT NULL then using `gsub`(Global substitution) function to substitute `(effect)\n` and `\n+[[:space:]]*$`(new lines followed by spaces at end of value) with NULL in RT. Then splitting value of `RT` into array named `arr` with delimiter of ORS and saving its(total contents value OR array length value) into variable named `num`, then printing `sum=` along with value of `num` here to get required results.

With shown samples, output will be as follows:

```
sum=3
sum=4
sum=2
```

Comment: Does this work similar to for loop? because In my actual code I need to perform some additional operations with sum where the line prints sum=num

Comment: @Aprilian8, not exactly loop, see in `awk` by default new line will be record separator and in here I have change record separator to catch only required value(additional things can work depending upon what you are trying to work upon, this answer has been provided as per shown samples only as mentioned), request you to try it out once and let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Comment: Thanks it helps me bit. but when I add addtional if statement instead of print statement i got syntax error. awk -v RS='(^|\n)?\\(effect\\)[^(]*' '
RT{
  gsub(/\(effect\)\n|\n+[[:space:]]*$/,"",RT)
  num=split(RT,arr,ORS)
  (if num == 2){print "yes"}
}
'  sum.txt

Comment: @Aprilian8, I would like to request you to open a new question with all details and your efforts(as this question is already posted and may confuse users if being changed or expanded IMHO). One post one question is what encouraged on SO, cheers and happy learning 

Comment: I mentioned already I m looking for answer with for loop

Comment: @Aprilian8, agreed but for your shown samples, this code and all other codes work(without loop because for shown samples loop is not needed), so that's why I requested to open a new question with all details in it because without seeing/knowing samples its hard to answer, now many users have responded with answer and it will create confusion, so if you feel you could ask a new question with all details in it, kindly go ahead, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk '{sum += $1} $0=="(effect)" && NR>1 {print "sum=" sum; sum=0} 
END{print "sum=" sum}' file

sum=3
sum=4
sum=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Ravinder's answer, but does not depend on the name of the header:

```sh
awk -v RS='' -v FS='\n' '{
    sum = 0
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i
    printf "sum=%d\n", sum
}' file
```

`RS=''` means that sequences of 2 or more newlines separate records.
The Field Separator is newline.
The for loop omits field #1, the header.

However that means that empty lines truly need to be empty: no spaces or tabs allowed. If your data might have blank lines that contain whitespace, you can set

```
-v RS='\n[[:space:]]*\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='(effect)' 'NR>1{sum=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print "sum="sum}' file

sum=3
sum=4
sum=2
```